# I exported a react js component but when i start my app it not displaying the output

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Hi i am new in coding and trying to build a react app. I just create a react component named login.js and export it as default and import it in app.js, but as i start my react app the div that i written in login.js is not displaying on the display.

Login.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
// import styled from 'styled-components';

const Login = ( props ) => {
    return( 
        <div>hello world</div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

App.js code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my app output:
[output after running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZH4g.png)

it is exported because it showing this :
[proof that the component is exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08E6B.png)

I tried so many ways but nothing worked. Plz help

Comment: if you are using react router dom v6, you need to pass `Login` component to the `element` props of `Route`. So `<Route exact path="/" element={Login} />` should work. 
If you are using v5, the code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the document of `react-router-dom`, you will need to specify your component to a prop named `element`.

```
<Route exact path='/' element={<Login />} />
```

[See more here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route)

Comment: Thanks bro it worked, but the guy whom I followed used same code which i written here and it worked for him. Can you please explain me why its not working for me.

Comment: I believe you are using "react-router-dom" v6 and your friend using v5.